# database suddenly no response after modify process file

Tags: php, mysql

i've a problem my database become no response..i'm using one page process for many form..last time it can works normally,where is my fault:

```
switch(postVar('action')) {
        case 'newinputdata' : newinputdata(postVar('modelnm'),postVar('serialno'),postVar('faline'),postVar('shift'),postVar('insp_date'),postVar('range_sampl'),postVar('pack'),post$
                break;
}
```

and for query:

```
function newinputdata($modelnm,$serialno,$faline,$shift,$insp_date,$range_sampl,$pack,$acc,$app,$tuner_rng,$gen,$remark,$NIK,$time) {

        $Model=mysql_real_escape_string($modelnm);
        $Serial_number=mysql_real_escape_string($serialno);
        $Line=mysql_real_escape_string($faline);
        $Shift=mysql_real_escape_string($shift);
        $Inspection_date=mysql_real_escape_string($insp_date);
        $Range_sampling=mysql_real_escape_string($range_sampl);
        $Packing=mysql_real_escape_string($pack);
        $Accesories=mysql_real_escape_string($acc);
        $Appearance=mysql_real_escape_string($app);
        $Tuner=mysql_real_escape_string($tuner_rng);
        $General_operation=mysql_real_escape_string($gen);
        $Remark=mysql_real_escape_string($remark);
        $NIK=mysql_real_escape_string($NIK);
        $Time_inspection=mysql_real_escape_string($time);


//build query


     $sql = "INSERT INTO inspection_report ";
      $sql.= "(Model,       Serial_number,       Line,        Shift,     Inspection_datetime,         Range_sampling,       Packing, ";
      $sql.= "Accesories,       Appearance,      Tuner,        General_operation,       Remark, ";
      $sql.= "NIK, Time_inspection) ";
      $sql.= "VALUES ('";
      $sql.= $Model."','".$Serial_number."', '".$Line."','".$Shift."','".postVar('insp_date')." ".postVar('time')."','".$Range_sampling."','".$Packing."','";
      $sql.= $Accesories."','".$Appearance."','".$Tuner."','".$General_operation."','".$Remark."','";
      $sql.= $NIK."','".$Time_inspection."')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$dbc) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
echo $result;
mysql_close($dbc);
}
```

Comment: your function call have missing parameters on it please check

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but if your code worked fine before and now your database isn't responding, it's probably a database problem, nto a code problem. Did you check to make sure it's still running?

Comment: before it happen..i've been delete some parameter bcoz it not use again..and change fieldname at db from inspection_date into inspection_datetime

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no response"?  What exactly happens?  Have you checked that there aren't any connections that might have locked the table?  Try `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: firebug shows that "Serial_number" undefined...but i'm not change that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've been found the sucker problem..i'm just make a little change after that my program can work properly:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
//echo $result;
mysql_close($dbc);
}
```